# Hubspot Landing Page Styles

Tags: html, css, hubspot

I'm having trouble overriding the html styles when creating a landing page in HubSpot. I want to add

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

but it keeps defaulting to

```
html {
  overflow: auto
}
```

I've tried `!important`, adding it to the head, to the footer, to a custom html module, etc. but I cannot override the default HubSpot styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specificity: if the html tag has a class or id attribute, then select it to override the native one.

```
html.page {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Either that, or inline the style into the html page if you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

please disable include stylesheet.

`Primary CSS File : Disable` and

```
Include Domain Stylesheets : Disable
```

Then apply

`html.no-js { overflow-x:hidden !important; }`